# Structs - expression must be a modifiable value

Tags: c++, struct

I'm new to structs and I'm struggling a bit.
I have the following struct:

```
typedef struct 
{
    CHAR_t bWpId[10];
    CHAR_t bWpDescr[25];
    UINT16_t wCoA;
    sUtmCoordinate_t Coordinate;
} sWaypoint_t;

typedef struct
{
    sWaypointListElement Element[cMAX_WAYPOINTS];
    UINT8_t bHead;
    UINT8_t bTail;
    UINT8_t bNumElements;
} sWaypointList;
```

Now each waypoint is an element in a waypointlist which is also a struct.

```
class CWaypointList
{
    private:
        sWaypointList WaypointList;
}
```

Now my question is how do I read in values in each element of the struct without writing accessors? Is accessors the only way to access the data within a private struct?

If I do it like this I get the error : expression must be a modifiable value.:

```
 element.bWpId = {'0','0','0','0','0','0','0','0','0','1'};
```

Comment: What is the type of element?

Comment: It is of the type sWaypoint_t: 
     sWaypoint_t element;
which is a struct
      typedef struct 
      {
 CHAR_t bWpId[10];
 CHAR_t bWpDescr[25];
 UINT16_t wCoA;
 sUtmCoordinate_t Coordinate;
     }sWaypoint_t;

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't use that syntax to initialize an array outside of the arrays definition. You have to fill in all values manually.

Fortunately there are standard C++ functions to do that for use, like [`std::fill`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/fill):

```
std::fill(std::begin(element.bWpId), std::end(element.bWpId), '0');
element.bWpId[9] = '1';
```

---

You can of course make a constructor for the `sWaypoint_t` structure, and initialize the array in that:

```
typedef struct sWaypoint_s
{
    CHAR_t bWpId[10];
    CHAR_t bWpDescr[25];
    UINT16_t wCoA;
    sUtmCoordinate_t Coordinate;

    sWaypoint_s()
        : bWpId{'0','0','0','0','0','0','0','0','0','1'}
        {}
} sWaypoint_t;
```

The problem with this is that it requires a C++11 capable compiler.

Comment: And if I do it like this:
 
      CHAR_t bId[10] = {'0','0','0','0','0','0','0','0','0','1'};
      element.bWpId = bId;

Comment: @user2633955 No, you simply can't assign to an array after a declaration. You can on the other hand copy from one to the other though, like `std::copy(std::begin(bld), std::end(bld), std::begin(element.bWpId));`

Comment: Isn't there a way to initialize it with the according values?

Comment: @user2633955 If all instances should have the same value, and you have a C++11 compiler, then you can do it in a constructor. See e.g. my updated answer.

Comment: Yes that is true. The problem of initializing in the constructor is that I need to make more than one sWaypoint object and initialize them with values. I'm doing test cases for this CWaypointList class

Comment: This also works if you want to send in different values:

CHAR_t bId[10] = {0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1};
for (UINT8_t bCount = 0; bCount < 10; bCount++)
{
   element.bWpId[bCount] = bId[bCount];
}
Thanks for all the tips, advice and answers!You really helped alot. :)

Answer (score 0):

In C++ you can not list-initialise array that has already been constructed. Same applies for list-initialising structures.

Using `std::fill` is one way, but I dislike its obscurity. Instead you can try using this helper function:

```
template <class T, size_t Size>
void copy_array(T (&dst)[Size], const T (&src)[Size])
{
    std::copy(src, src+Size, dst);
}
```

Now you can "assign" any array. In the case of `element.bWpId`:

```
CHAR_t temp[] = {'0','0','0','0','0','0','0','0','0','1'};
copy_array(element.bWpId, temp);
```

The function will compile-time check arrays types and sizes, so it leaves no opportunity for a mistake. Which is a huge advantage over explicit std::fill and manual indexing.

All that provided you don't have access to C++11 compiler. If you have, just change the `bWpId` to `std::array<Char_t, 10>` and then you can list-initialise it anytime you want.

Answer (score 0):

I used sprintf(element.bId,'0');